# Puppet: don't manage single line(s) in a template

Tags: puppet

I have defined a config file in my puppet manifest and I need to use an .erb template so I can load in dynamic parameters.

The problem is however that the application insists on changing a couple of lines in that file prior to puppet running. Such lines cannot be easily discovered and put into the template (for example, a build number that increments). If I tell puppet to refresh the service when the config file changes, then every puppet run I have my service being restarted, which isn't good.

Is there any way that I could use an .erb template with Puppet but tell it not to care if specific lines in it change? I'm not sure if this is possible or even if it's going to work, but it would be good to know.

Cheers

Comment: Can your config file `include` another config file which can be managed by puppet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either a `file_line` resource from stdlib module or an `augeas` lens to instruct puppet about what lines do you want at the config file. Those lines will be puppet managed, and rest of file will rest unchanged.

Comment: Yes, although `file_line` is not namespaced to `stdlib`, even though you need the module to get the type.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like `file_line` or `augeas` (one is a bit of a hack and the other difficult to figure out), you might have to create a [custom fact](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/custom_facts.html) to inform the master of the current state of the file. The master could then apply logic to update that content only if necessary.

Granted, that's not much more intuitive or maintainable than the aforementioned methods.